# V8 C++, remove last element from array

Tags: c++, arrays, v8

I'm building a native NodeJS module for NodeJs and I'm wondering how can I remove the last element from array?

```
 Local<Array> nodes = Array::New();
```

I've tried, `nodes->Remove()`, `nodes->Splice()`, `nodes->Pop()`, but none of them works.

Thanks.

And yes, I [googled it](https://www.google.bg/search?q=v8%20c%2b%2b%20remove%20last%20element%20of%20array&oq=v8%20c%2b%2b%20remove%20last%20element%20of%20array&aqs=chrome..69i57.6678j0j7&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8) and couldn't find a proper answer.

Comment: @Deepsy: please reduce your questions to one subquestion.

Comment: I've being doing this in the past hour and couldn't find anything. I also tried to look at some open source modules, but couldn't find an array pop. https://www.google.bg/search?q=v8+c%2B%2B+remove+last+element+of+array&oq=v8+c%2B%2B+remove+last+element+of+array&aqs=chrome..69i57.6678j0j7&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8 I dont see any answer to my question on the first 2 pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After few hours research, I found this [source code](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/WebCore/WebCore-658.28/bindings/v8/V8Utilities.cpp) and figured out that

```
nodes->Delete(ID);
```

will do the job.